# How to Include the format of the JSON Response Body in the docs generated by Enunciate?

Tags: maven, enunciate

Currently Enunciate generates the REST API documentation, but the *Response Body* doesn't contain the information about the JSON structure of the response. In my understanding, if I include the classes with the data entities that are serialized/de-serialized by Jersey to JSON, enunciate would be able to generate that piece of the documentation.

The data entities are in a different module, which is packaged with its sources as suggested in the enunciate documentation - [Multi-Module Projects](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/Multi-Module+Projects)

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
...
```

This is how my **enunciate.xml** looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<enunciate label="someapi" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://enunciate.codehaus.org/schemas/enunciate-1.25.xsd">

    <api-import pattern="com.something.business.vo.**"/>
    <api-import pattern="com.something.business.domain.**"/>

    <api-classes>
        <include pattern="com.something.web.ssoApi.rest.*"/>
        <include pattern="com.something.business.vo.**"/>
        <include pattern="com.something.business.domain.**"/>
    </api-classes>

</enunciate>
```

And this how the docs look like:

[image: Documentation Screenshot]

As you see the Response Body contains just `element: (custom)`.

How to make that contain the JSON structure of the response?

Comment: It seems that in order to generate the documentation for the Data Model section, the entities should be annotated with `@XmlRoolElement`. Is that correct or I can use a different annotation, so that to include only the JSON in the docs without the XML?

Comment: `<docs title="REST API" includeExampleXml="false"></docs>` This setting disables the generation of the xml sample and leaves only the JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to generate the documentation for the Data Model section, the entities should be annotated with `@XmlRootElement`.